How long to wait after transfer trx before can burn it as bandwidth?
In tron, to transfer trx I need bandwidth, say I need transfer 0.34 trx from A to B, and get tx-hash #1.
B don't have enough bandwidth, and it will transfer some trx to C, thus will burn the trx it just get from C, and get tx-hash #2.
How to long do I need to wait between tx-hash #1 and tx-hash #2?
Do I just need to wait for the next block, or wait for confirmation, or I don't need to wait at all?

Based on the documentation here The consumed resources bandwidth will be recovered in 24 hours, for example, if you have spent 240 bandwidth in 1st transaction then every hour will recover 240/24 = 10 bandwidth.

Read the question again what u described is not relevant.
